# Adding an assisting editor box to Post page

Tags: post-meta, metabox

I run a multiple author platform and to improve the moderation, I want to add a couple of assisting editors. I want to add a custom box to the Post page where the assisting editor can confirm which tasks they have completed.

So, this box would contain a checklist of options, for example:

> ```
>     1 => ' Proofread ',
>     2 => ' Graphics Added ',
>     3 => ' SEO Fixed ',
>     4 => ' Ready for Publish '
> ```

And then contain a checklist that lists all assisting editors (users that can `edit_published_posts`) and there the user can mark themselves as they have contributed to the edit.

The box could look like this:

[image: Editorial Tasks]

Then finally, on the front end post page, I want to list which user(s) that have edited the post.

In an attempt to do this, I have this code:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'assisting_editor' );
function assisting_editor() {
    add_meta_box(
        'assisting_editor', // id, used as the html id att
        __( 'Editorial Tasks' ), // meta box title
        'editor_tasks', // callback function, spits out the content
        'post', // post type or page. This adds to posts only
        'side', // context, where on the screen
        'low' // priority, where should this go in the context
    );

}

function editor_tasks( $post ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rating', true);
    echo '<div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last"><span id="timestamp"><label>Editorial tasks: </label>';

    $ratings = array(
        1 => ' Proofread ',
        2 => ' Graphics Added ',
        3 => ' SEO Fixed ',
        4 => ' Ready for Publish '
    );

    echo '<select name="rating">';
    echo '<option value=""' . ((($value == '') || !isset($ratings[$value])) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '> Untouched </option>';

    // output each rating as an option
    foreach ($ratings as $id => $text) {
        echo '<option value="' . $id . '"' . (($value == $id) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '">' . $text. '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';

    echo '</span></div>';
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_metadata');

function save_metadata($postid)
{   
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return false;
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $postid ) ) return false;
    if( empty($postid) ) return false;


    if ( is_null($_REQUEST["rating"]) ) {
        delete_post_meta($postid, 'rating');
    } else {
        update_post_meta($postid, 'rating', $_REQUEST['rating']);
    }

}
```

**However**, this code adds a drop-down list, not a check-list, and more importantly, it does not list the editor users.

**My question is**: how can I make a box like the picture above and with those features, and how do I echo the list of users that have edited the post?

Comment: You want `checkbox`, but have `select` in your above code. Question: Do you know basic HTML?

Comment: @kaiser I am self-taught and learning as we speak. I only know what I have practiced so far which is limited. I would not know how to adjust that example code to make it do what I want, especially listing the editor users in the front end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) should give you the box container like your have pictured.

You have a select drop-down because that is what you created here:

```
echo '<select name="rating">';
echo '<option value=""' . ((($value == '') || !isset($ratings[$value])) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '> Untouched </option>';

// output each rating as an option
foreach ($ratings as $id => $text) {
    echo '<option value="' . $id . '"' . (($value == $id) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '">' . $text. '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

You need a series of [checkboxes](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlcheckboxes.php). Of the code above you only need the `foreach`. Checkboxes work differently that selects. The following will give you four different values that you need to save, one for each element of your `$ratings` array.

```
foreach ($ratings as $id => $text) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.strtolower($text).'" value="' . $id . '"' . (($value == $id) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '"/><label for"'.strtolower($text).'">'.$text.'</label>';
}
```

You can put all of the checkboxes in an array by naming them like this:

```
foreach ($ratings as $id => $text) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="ratings[]" value="' . $id . '"' . (($value == $id) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '"/><label for"ratings[]">'.$text.'</label>';
}
```

In the first case you will have to modify your update function. In the second, I believe your function will work but I am not 100% sure.

To get your list of authors you want to use [`get_users`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) with the `who` parameter set to 'authors' which will, per the codex, return "user level greater than 0". That is, everyone who isn't a subscriber-- authors, editors, contributors, etc. So...

```
$alleds = get_users('who=authors');
```

Another check to see if any any authors are already selected.

```
$currenteds = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'currenteds', true);
```

And then a `foreach` to create the checkboxes, much like the one above for `$ratings`. You want that last parameter `true` only if you save as a single entry in the DB, which probably makes sense in this case.

```
foreach ($alleds as $ed) {
    $checked = (in_array($ed->ID,$currenteds)) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="currenteds[]" value="' . $ed->ID . '"' . $checked . '"/><label for"ratings[]">'.$ed->user_nicename.'</label>';
}
```

And of course another `update_post_meta` block to save the fields.

```
if ( is_null($_REQUEST["currenteds"]) ) {
    delete_post_meta($postid, 'currenteds');
} else {
    update_post_meta($postid, 'currenteds', $_REQUEST['currenteds']);
}
```

I think that's got it.

Also, you are passing dirty data into these function. I won't lecture but look up "data validation" and "data sanitization" . :)

Here is the whole thing with a couple of typo corrections and bug fixes. Our editors have bugged me for something similar so I mocked it up :). The formatting is non-existent but it works. I tested it as a plugin, so build yourself a [plugin header](http://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header#Plugin_File_Header_Example). I don't know if it will work from `function.php`.

```
// author checkboxes
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'assisting_editor' );
function assisting_editor() {
    add_meta_box(
        'assisting_editor', // id, used as the html id att
        __( 'Editorial Tasks' ), // meta box title
        'editor_tasks', // callback function, spits out the content
        'post', // post type or page. This adds to posts only
        'side', // context, where on the screen
        'low' // priority, where should this go in the context
    );

}

function editor_tasks( $post ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ratings', true);

    echo '<div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last"><span id="timestamp"><label>Editorial tasks: </label>';

    $ratings = array(
        1 => ' Proofread ',
        2 => ' Graphics Added ',
        3 => ' SEO Fixed ',
        4 => ' Ready for Publish '
    );

    foreach ($ratings as $id => $text) {
    $checked = (in_array($id,(array)$value)) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="ratings[]" value="' . $id . '"'.  $checked . '/><label for="ratings[]">'.$text.'</label>';
    }

    $qry['relation'] = 'OR';
    $qry[] = array(
      'key' => $wpdb->prefix.'capabilities',
      'value' => 'editor',
      'compare' => 'like'
    );
    $qry[] = array(
      'key' => $wpdb->prefix.'capabilities',
      'value' => 'administrator',
      'compare' => 'like'
    );
    $qry = array('fields' => 'all_with_meta','meta_query'=>$qry);

    $alleds = get_users($qry);

    $currenteds = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'currenteds', true);

    foreach ($alleds as $ed) {
    $checked = (in_array($ed->ID,(array)$currenteds)) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="currenteds[]" value="' . $ed->ID . '"' .$checked . '"/><label for="ratings[]">'.$ed->user_nicename.'</label>';
    }
    echo '</span></div>';
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_metadata');

function save_metadata($postid)
{   
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return false;
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $postid ) ) return false;
    if( empty($postid) ) return false;

    if ( is_null($_REQUEST["ratings"]) ) {
        delete_post_meta($postid, 'ratings');
    } else {
        update_post_meta($postid, 'ratings', $_REQUEST['ratings']);
    }

    if ( is_null($_REQUEST["currenteds"]) ) {
    delete_post_meta($postid, 'currenteds');
    } else {
    update_post_meta($postid, 'currenteds', $_REQUEST['currenteds']);
    }
}

function display_current_eds($ID = '') {
  if (empty($ID)) {
    global $post;
    if (!empty($post)) {
      $ID = $post->ID;
    }
  }
  if (empty($ID)) return false;
  $eds = get_post_meta($post->ID,'currenteds',true);
  if (!empty($eds)) {
    foreach ($eds as $e) {
      $edu = get_userdata($e);
      $edusers[] = sprintf(
        '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="author">%3$s</a>',
        get_author_posts_url( $edu->ID, $edu->user_nicename ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Posts by %s' ), $edu->user_nicename ) ),
        $edu->user_nicename
      );
    }
    return $edusers;
  }
  return false;
}

function authors_content_filter($content) {
  $authors = display_current_eds();
  if (false !== $authors) {
    $content .= implode(', ',$authors);
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','authors_content_filter');

    // add author checkboxes
```

The `add_filter` will display authors automatically. To display the authors manually use the following inside the Loop:

```
$edusers = display_current_eds();
if (false !== $edusers) {
    echo implode(', ',$edusers);
}
```

I am going to leave it to you to work out formatting and other bells and whistles. I think this question has now been more than adequately answered.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, your answer did not include how I list all assisting editors in a checklist and how I echo these in the front end post page. Do you know how to do this? (thank you regardless for your input)

Comment: yes... your are right. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I look forward to the edit. Ideally, if you could post the whole function and I will be able to test it instantly and report back.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and paste the whole code there as I tried to piece it together but I must have made a mistake as it did not work as proposed.

Comment: I just tested your code but there are still issues with it. Firstly, if you check several options (like Proofread and Graphics) it will not save them once post is updated. Secondly, the admin list does not function, it lists authors too. Do you know why?

Comment: Try again. It is the same except for the `editor_tasks` function.

Comment: My apologies for not responding earlier, my account was temp suspended. Nonetheless, I just tested your code and it works excellently. However, my final question is, how do I print the selected users usernames within the post (front end)? So for instance, it displays "Post edited by X and X..."

Comment: You want to run [`get_post_meta`[(http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) in your Loop for each post on the front end, take the results, format them however you want and echo them. Or you can create a filter for `the_content`, for example, and automatically echo. I tend to edit the theme because I write all my themes from scratch and there is no worry of having an update clobber things.

Comment: Can you kindly update your answer with code examples of these two solutions? I will then test it and further debug if it is working properly. Eventually, I will release this (including a great couple of other features) as a plugin and will of course credit you.

Comment: I used your '$edusers = display_current_eds();'... code and it echoed the usernames twice. Why? Is there a typo there? I can read the code but can't find why it is behaving like that.

Comment: You can't use that manual code and also leave the filter on `the_content` or you will get the names output twice.

Comment: Ah right, got it! Thank you very much for your endless support. I have upvoted this and accepted as correct. I will comment here within the next few weeks and give an update on the plugin. Thanks again.