# Limit checklist by the current user

Tags: php, metabox, list

Bare with me as I explain this. I'm adding an Assistant Editor feature to my multiple author platform. In the box that appears in post-edit page, the Editors can tick which task that they have done (for instance proofread the article) and then check their username (so that they will be credited on the front post page). The box looks something like this:

[image]

The code for the box:

```
// author checkboxes
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'assisting_editor' );
function assisting_editor() {
    add_meta_box(
        'assisting_editor', // id, used as the html id att
        __( 'Editorial Tasks' ), // meta box title
        'editor_tasks', // callback function, spits out the content
        'post', // post type or page. This adds to posts only
        'side', // context, where on the screen
        'low' // priority, where should this go in the context
    );

}

function editor_tasks( $post ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ratings', true);

    echo '<div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last"><span id="timestamp"><label>Editorial tasks: </label>';

    $ratings = array(
        1 => ' Proofread ',
        2 => ' Graphics Added ',
        3 => ' SEO Fixed ',
        4 => ' Ready for Publish '
    );

    foreach ($ratings as $id => $text) {
    $checked = (in_array($id,(array)$value)) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="ratings[]" value="' . $id . '"'.  $checked . '/><label for="ratings[]">'.$text.'</label>';
    }

    $qry['relation'] = 'OR';
    $qry[] = array(
      'key' => $wpdb->prefix.'capabilities',
      'value' => 'editor',
      'compare' => 'like'
    );
    $qry[] = array(
      'key' => $wpdb->prefix.'capabilities',
      'value' => 'administrator',
      'compare' => 'like'
    );
    $qry = array('fields' => 'all_with_meta','meta_query'=>$qry);

    $alleds = get_users($qry);

    $currenteds = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'currenteds', true);

    foreach ($alleds as $ed) {
    $checked = (in_array($ed->ID,(array)$currenteds)) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="currenteds[]" value="' . $ed->ID . '"' .$checked . '"/><label for="ratings[]">'.$ed->user_nicename.'</label>';
    }
    echo '</span></div>';
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_metadata');

function save_metadata($postid)
{   
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return false;
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $postid ) ) return false;
    if( empty($postid) ) return false;

    if ( is_null($_REQUEST["ratings"]) ) {
        delete_post_meta($postid, 'ratings');
    } else {
        update_post_meta($postid, 'ratings', $_REQUEST['ratings']);
    }

    if ( is_null($_REQUEST["currenteds"]) ) {
    delete_post_meta($postid, 'currenteds');
    } else {
    update_post_meta($postid, 'currenteds', $_REQUEST['currenteds']);
    }
}

function display_current_eds($ID = '') {
  if (empty($ID)) {
    global $post;
    if (!empty($post)) {
      $ID = $post->ID;
    }
  }
  if (empty($ID)) return false;
  $eds = get_post_meta($post->ID,'currenteds',true);
  if (!empty($eds)) {
    foreach ($eds as $e) {
      $edu = get_userdata($e);
      $edusers[] = sprintf(
        '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="author">%3$s</a>',
        get_author_posts_url( $edu->ID, $edu->user_nicename ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Posts by %s' ), $edu->user_nicename ) ),
        $edu->user_nicename
      );
    }
    return $edusers;
  }
  return false;
}

function authors_content_filter($content) {
  $authors = display_current_eds();
  if (false !== $authors) {
    $content .= implode(', ',$authors);
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','authors_content_filter');

    // add author checkboxes
```

Now, the problem is that the user can tick his own name **and any of the other editors**. This means that the user can as well untick any of the names too. That is not good.

My question is, how do I make it so that the user can only tick his own name and the other names are greyed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same technique as $checked:

```
$disabled = ( $ed->ID != get_current_user_id() ) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';
```

your code:

```
foreach ($alleds as $ed) {
    $checked = (in_array($ed->ID,(array)$currenteds)) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    $disabled = ( $ed->ID != get_current_user_id() ) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="currenteds[]" value="' . $ed->ID . '"' . $checked . $disabled . '"/><label for="ratings[]">'.$ed->user_nicename.'</label>';
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate where exactly I would add that code?

Comment: And what about if I want to display the full list for Admins?

Comment: I updated my answer. To keep all things checkable for admins, try: `$disabled = ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) ? '' : ( $ed->ID != get_current_user_id() ) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';`

Comment: Please update your answer with that solution. Also, can you please elaborate how this will work? Will it grey out the list or simply not display the other usernames?

Comment: There appears to be one serious problem with this code. If a list item is already checked but visually disabled when the user loads it up, when that user updates the post, the disabled list item will be unchecked. Diggy, is there any way to prevent that problem? Please let me know if I did not explain this good.

Answer (score 2):

Check the editor IDs against the current user ID and add `disabled="disabled"` if they don't match.

```
$current_user = get_currentuseinfo();
foreach ($alleds as $ed) {
    $checked = (in_array($ed->ID,(array)$currenteds)) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    $disabled = (!current_user_can('administrator') && $current_user->ID !== $ed->ID) ? ' disabled="disabled" : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="currenteds[]" value="' . $ed->ID . '"' .$checked . '" '.$disabled.' /><label for="ratings[]">'.$ed->user_nicename.'</label>';
}
```

Be aware that this is not foolproof. I can bypass that in under 10 seconds. Consider that a visual convenience only. You'd want to do the same thing when you save the data. That is trickier. I think I would change this:

```
if ( is_null($_REQUEST["currenteds"]) ) {
    delete_post_meta($postid, 'currenteds');
} else {
    update_post_meta($postid, 'currenteds', $_REQUEST['currenteds']);
}
```

To something more like:

```
// admins have full capabilities
if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
    if ( is_null($_REQUEST["currenteds"]) ) {
        delete_post_meta($postid, 'currenteds');
    } else {
        update_post_meta($postid, 'currenteds', $_REQUEST['currenteds']);
    }
} else {
   $meta_values = get_post_meta($postid, 'currenteds', true);
   // I don't remember what the relevant arrays look like
   // even though I wrote much of that code :)
   // Here is the idea
   // Check the IDs in $meta_values against the IDs in $_REQUEST['currenteds']
   // and only allow manipulation of IDs that match get_currentuserinfo()->ID
   // I'll have to install the code to do better but if you can't get it I will.
}
```

Two modified methods, lightly tested.

```
function editor_tasks( $post ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ratings', true);

    echo '<div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last"><span id="timestamp"><label>Editorial tasks: </label>';

    $ratings = array(
        1 => ' Proofread ',
        2 => ' Graphics Added ',
        3 => ' SEO Fixed ',
        4 => ' Ready for Publish '
    );

    foreach ($ratings as $id => $text) {
    $checked = (in_array($id,(array)$value)) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="ratings[]" value="' . $id . '"'.  $checked . '/><label for="ratings[]">'.$text.'</label>';
    }

    $qry['relation'] = 'OR';
    $qry[] = array(
      'key' => $wpdb->prefix.'capabilities',
      'value' => 'editor',
      'compare' => 'like'
    );
    $qry[] = array(
      'key' => $wpdb->prefix.'capabilities',
      'value' => 'administrator',
      'compare' => 'like'
    );
    $qry = array('fields' => 'all_with_meta','meta_query'=>$qry);

    $alleds = get_users($qry);

    $currenteds = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'currenteds', true);

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    foreach ($alleds as $ed) {
    $checked = (in_array($ed->ID,(array)$currenteds)) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    $disabled = (!current_user_can('administrator') && $current_user->ID !== $ed->ID) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="currenteds[]" value="' . $ed->ID . '" ' .$checked . ' '.$disabled.' /><label for="ratings[]">'.$ed->user_nicename.'</label>';
    }
    echo '</span></div>';
}
```

And...

```
function save_metadata($postid)
{
    $rid = wp_is_post_revision($postid);
    if ($postid !== $rid) $postid = $rid;

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return false;
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $postid ) ) return false;
    if( empty($postid) ) return false;

    if (!empty($_REQUEST['ratings'])) {
      if ( is_null($_REQUEST["ratings"]) ) {
      delete_post_meta($postid, 'ratings');
      } else {
      update_post_meta($postid, 'ratings', $_REQUEST['ratings']);
      }
    }

    // admins have full capabilities
    if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
    if ( is_null($_REQUEST["currenteds"]) ) {
        delete_post_meta($postid, 'currenteds');
    } else {
        update_post_meta($postid, 'currenteds', $_REQUEST['currenteds']);
    }
    } else {
      global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();
      $meta_values = get_post_meta($postid, 'currenteds', true);
      if (!empty($_REQUEST["currenteds"]) && in_array($current_user->ID,$_REQUEST["currenteds"])) {
    $meta_values[] = "$current_user->ID";
      } else {
    $u = array_search($current_user->ID,$meta_values);
    var_dump($u);
    if (false !== $u) {
      unset($meta_values[$u]);
    }
      }
      $meta_values = array_unique($meta_values);
      update_post_meta($postid, 'currenteds', $meta_values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is easy to bypass it with Firebug or similar. Great to have the original coder of this feature here! Is there any chance that you can do a testrun of the data save solution to confirm if it does work as proposed?

Comment: I can test it but I can't promise when. I have a busy morning.

Comment: Take your time and please keep me updated. Thank you. I will leave this question open until then.

Comment: I have another question for you if you don't mind. It appears that `authors_content_filter` displays the Editors after the content no matter where I execute it. How can I display it elsewhere (within the loop though). I want to place it where I have the meta info (where I list date of post etc).

Comment: That last question is easy. I have time for that. :) Just call `display_current_eds()` directly and `echo` the output. Skip the filter.

Comment: Yup! That works great! Please keep me updated if you find the time to review the data save solution.

Comment: It appears that I can now display it anywhere I want, but the Editor list is still being echo'd after the content, why? I could solve it by removing the filter from the source code but should that really be necessary?

Comment: Yes, you have to remove the filter or make a more system that selectively adds it. That was an example not an integral part of the system. I believe this same thing came up in [the original thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72427/adding-an-assisting-editor-box-to-post-page).

Comment: Great update to your answer, although can you please explain the edit? Are those two separate methods or one solution? If they are separate, which one would you suggest that I use?

Comment: Those replace the methods of the same name in the original code. You need both of them.

Comment: Thank you. I will test this code for a day or two to see that it functions properly, I will report back and if it works, I will certainly accept this answer as correct and extend my gratitude.

Comment: Few tests gave these 2 main bugs/issues. **1)** If the current_user is not ticked when updating post, errors like this http://i.imgur.com/LxEWj.png and http://i.imgur.com/plR23.png comes up. This is a problem because, for instance, if the current_user is an Admin/Editor and is making a post, they would be forced to tick themselves (when in fact other editors are supposed to proofread etc the post). **2)** The second issue is that **Admins** cannot untick a user from a list, why? Once you update the post, the unticked user is ticked again. If you have time, can you kindly fix these 2 issues?

Comment: @ChristineCooper, respectfully, I am not here to write code for you. The point of the site is to provide help with particular problems, not write whole projects. You should be able to take what is given and adapt it. I have only written as much as I have because my editors are bugging me for something similar, otherwise it might fall into the "work for me for free" category mentioned in the [faq]. That said, there is an extra condition in `save_metadata` that I put in for testing. Look for `false && ` and remove it. That should fix #2. As for #1, I don't get those errors.

Comment: My apologies, my intention was not to at all to make you do all the work. I try to contribute as much as I can to this community as well (review my answer through profile). I was just glad that I connected with the developer of the original code and took the opportunity to perfect it. Also, my limited coding knowledge is preventing me from resolving this particular issue. Regarding the bug, on a fresh install of WP 3.5, with an editor account, I published a new post without ticking anything and the same error (+others) were displayed: http://i.imgur.com/JZcP7.png

Comment: Like I said, I have ulterior motives for this one. The error is almost certainly due to a missing `if (isset($parameter_name)` somewhere before trying to use `$parameter`.

Comment: I have a question regarding your code (its pasted in my question). It works elegantly, I have obviously made some major changes to it since I posted this question, however one problem remains: **Only** Editors can save changes, not Administrators. I am trying to understand why, is it related to the `$qry[] = array(` part of the code? What can I change to give Admins permission to make changes too? This issue has been bugging me for a week now so I thought I would ask the creator of this code.