# Put an extra check box on "Page Attributes" widget

Tags: multi-language, page-attributes

that will add `lang="ur"` attribute in page's main `<body>` tag. How I can do that? I try different plugin including polylang, but look not working. Please suggest plugin if you know or do some simple coding.

Comment: What does your question have to do with the "page attributes" widget?

Comment: @helgatheviking I want to add new Checkbox on the page attribute's widget.

Comment: If this is related to your other question about showing Custom Fields, you may consider a plugin like Advanced Custom Fields, or creating [your own Custom Meta Box](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72997/12615) if you're in coding mood.

Comment: Sorry it seems that your question is a continuation of your title, so I misunderstood. As brasofilio mentioned, you'll need to create a metabox, and then you can implement Patrick Saad's solution.

Comment: @brasofilo My other question is bit different from it. Here i want to add lang attribute only with title element. But there I want to add with body element.

Comment: There is no hook that would let you add a field to the "Page Attributes" box. However, adding a "language" meta box should not be hard. While the details are different, that is essentially [what was done here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72437/21376) if you want to investigate that path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom field, give it a value of **lang='ur'** and check for it in your header.php.

1. Add the custom field from the Custom Fields box. Let's call it **page_lang**. Give it a value of **lang='ur'**.

**In header.php**:

```
<?php
global $post;
$lang = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'page_lang', true);
?>
<body <?php body_class();?> <?php echo $lang;?>>
```

Each page you want to show this lang, you just select the '**page_lang**' custom field and give it the value you want (you have the option to write any value you want, thus any other language than 'ur').

Comment: Really thanks, that much simpler then I think. Thanks again