# Show or hide lang="ur" in main <body> element

Tags: custom-field, customization

I have RTL website in URDU language. `lang="ur"` is hard coded in main body i.e. `<body lang="ur" <?php body_class(); ?>>`. Now I want to replace attribute with some PHP code that will show or hide it on specific conditions.

I want that on page editing screen, there will radio buttons. When we select "Remove", remove `lang="ur"` from current page & otherwise leave it remain.

Comment: Can you post the body tag from your template?

Comment: @birgire this code is from theme's `header.php`: `<body lang="ur" <?php body_class(); ?>>`

Comment: You already went through this issue http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116884/put-an-extra-check-box-on-page-attributes-widget/116885#116885. The difference is you want a radio button instead of writing a custom field value, consider using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this attribute is hardcoded into your *body* tag.

You could adjust it with your own `body_lang()` function like this (untested) :

```
<body 
   <?php ( function_exists( 'body_lang' ) ) ? body_lang() : '' ;?> 
   <?php body_class(); ?>
>
```

where you can define the following, in your `functions.php` file:

```
/**
 * Display the language attribute part for the body element.
 *
 * @param string $lang.
 * @return void.
 */

if( ! function_exists( 'body_lang' ) )
{
    function body_lang( $lang = '' )
    {
         if( function_exists( 'get_body_lang' ) )
             echo get_body_lang( $lang );
    }
} // end if function exists
```

and

```
/**
 * Retrieve the language part for the body element.
 *
 * @param string $lang.
 * @return string $lang.
 */

if( ! function_exists( 'get_body_lang' ) )
{
    function get_body_lang( $lang = '' )
    {
        // default language
        $lang = ( ! empty( $lang ) ) ? $lang : 'ur';        

        // add your own logic here:
        if( is_single() )
            $lang = 'de';

        elseif( is_page() )
            $lang = 'en';

        $attr = sprintf( 'lang="%s"', $lang );

        return apply_filters( 'body_lang', $attr );
    }

} // end if function exists
```

where the filter `body_lang`  gives you further control.

To remove it, according to your own special logic, you can for example use:

```
/**
 * Remove the language part according to a custom logic
 *
 * @param string $attr.
 * @return string $attr.
 */

 function my_body_lang( $attr )
 {
     // add your own logic here:
     if( is_single() )
     { 

         // get the post meta value for 'language'. 
         // It can be 'Yes', 'No' or empty
         $show = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'language', TRUE );

         // Let's hide it if it's empty or 'No'
         if( empty( $show ) || "No" === $show )
             $attr = '';

     }

     return $attr;
 }

add_filter( 'body_lang', 'my_body_lang' );
```

Hopefully this points you towards a solution.

Comment: Thank you for response. I got idea from you answer. But there is something going wrong. Please check updated question.

Comment: I finally tested this, and it works now on my install ;-) I think you can use my solution with your new idea, but maybe your new idea deserves a new question.

Comment: I updated the answer to check for the post meta value 'language'. This value can be Yes, No or empty, according to the code you pasted above. If it's No or Empty then the language attribute is not disiplayed.